# Silverlight 3 - 3D Engine

Tags: silverlight, 3d

I understand that with the new Projection feature of Silverlight 3, it should be relatively easy to display simple 3D objects like cubes. Is there a 3D engine in works, that uses those SL 3 features to produce 3D scenes?

I know that there is Kit3D, but it seems it still runs on SL 1 or 2 and the project website is updated very rarely.

If there still is not such engine, I would need some help with my own. Using PlaneProjection, I made [this](http://home.arcor.de/neoinferno/Silverlight/Tesseract/) simple demo (move using WASD).

However, I have problems creating composite objects and transforming object positions according to the camera looking direction. I will provide more explanation and source code, if there is no engine that already does this.

Thanks,
Andrej

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check http://www.innoveware.com/quakelight.html too.
Edit: I thought it was opensource but I guess I was wrong....

Comment: Do you know, if QuakeLight uses WritableBitmap to render the whole 3D scene? It may be that my current approach using PlaneProjection may be not the one to take after all, if WritableBitmap is that more performant..

Comment: Quakelight is available under GPL, so you can download the source code and take a browse.